# how to dynamic change the text's content in A-FRAME?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the text content every two minuters.

```
var text = document.querySelector('a-entity');
text.setAttribute("text",{value:"nihao"});
```

I write the js code,but It doesn't work.
I need help

Comment: what errors do you get in the browser developer tools console? what is `A-FRAME`?

Comment: `text.setAttribute("text",{value:"nihao"});` is not how you use setAttribute ... try `text.setAttribute("text", "nihao");` instead

Comment: thanks very much,but use your method still donot work,the console show  Unknown property `0` for component/system `text`                                                                                 the entity is :                                                                                          <a-entity text="value:hello world; color:red; width:7" position="0 0 -5" ></a-entity>

Answer (score 0):

to change it on every 2 minutes use the `setInterval` like this

```
setInterval(function() {
    //if you are changing the text of input element
    let newText = getNewText();
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute('value', newText)
    //if you are changing the text of a div of p element
    document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerText =  newText
}, 2000)// every 2000 ms
```

read more about setInterval [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)